# Python : Match a dictionary value with another dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries created this way :

```
tr = defaultdict(list)
tr = { 'critic' : '2_critic', 
 'major' : '3_major',
 'all' : ['2_critic','3_major']
 }
```

And the second one :

```
scnd_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

And contains values like this :

```
scnd_dict = {'severity': ['all']}
```

I want to have a third dict that will contain the key of `scnd_dict` and its corresponding value from `tr`.
This way, I will have :

```
third_dict = {'severity' : ['2_critic','3_major']}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work :

```
for (k,v) in scnd_dict.iteritems() :
  if v in tr:
    third_dict[k].append(tr[v])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your value in the second dict is a list. How to determine what is “corresponding” to it?

Comment: for your first and second dict, defaultdict is overriden by the next affectation. it is a basic dict, not a defaultdict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

```
from collections import defaultdict

tr = {'critic' : '2_critic', 
      'major' : '3_major',
      'all' : ['2_critic','3_major']}

scnd_dict = {'severity': ['all']}

third_dict = {}

for k, v in scnd_dict.iteritems():
    vals = []
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for i in v:
            vals.append(tr.get(i))
    else:
        vals.append(tr.get(v))
    if not vals:
        continue
    third_dict[k] = vals

print third_dict
```

Results:

```
>>> 
{'severity': [['2_critic', '3_major']]}
```

Will do what you want. But I question the logic of using defaultdicts here, or of have your index part of a list...

---

If you use non-lists for `scnd_dict` then you can do the whole thing much easier. Assuming `scnd_dict` looks like this: `scnd_dict = {'severity': 'all'}`:

```
d = dict((k, tr.get(v)) for k, v in scnd_dict.items())
# {'severity': ['2_critic', '3_major']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I changed scnd_dict from defaultdict to dict() and I used your simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `v` is a list, not an item of a list. So, the `if v in tr:` will be false. Change your code so that you iterate over the items in `v`

Answer (score 0):

```
third_dict = {k: tr[v[0]] for k, v in scnd_dict.iteritems() if v[0] in tr}
```

This

```
tr = defaultdict(list)
```

is a waste of time if you are just rebinding `tr` on the next line. Likewise for `scnd_dict`.
It's a better idea to make *all* the values of `tr` lists - even if they only have one item. It will mean less special cases to worry about later on.

Comment: v is a list, it cannot work unless tr keys are lists, which they are not.

Answer (score 0):

```
third_dict = {k: [t for m in ks for t in tr[m]] for k,ks in scnd_dict.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second dict's value is list, not str, so the code blow will work

```
for (k, v) in send_dict.iteritems():
    if v[0] in tr.keys():
        third_dict[k] = tr[v[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the third dictionary does not knows that the values is a list

```
for k in scnd_dict:
    for v in scnd_dict[k]:
        print v
        for k2 in tr:
            if v==k2:
                if k not in third_dict:
                    third_dict[k]=tr[k2]
                else:
                    third_dict[k]+=tr[k2]
```